# ctags works but not for tagbar

Tags: ctags, plugin-tagbar

I'm working with typescript now, and I got this in my `~/.ctags` file:

```
--langdef=typescript
--langmap=typescript:.ts
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(export[ \t]+([a-z]+[ \t]+)?)?class[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\3/c,classes/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(declare[ \t]+)?namespace[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\2/c,modules/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(export[ \t]+)?module[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\2/n,modules/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(export[ \t]+)?(default[ \t]+)?(async[ \t]+)?function(\*)?[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\5/f,functions/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*export[ \t]+(var|let|const)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\2/v,variables/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(var|let|const)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*function[ \t]*[*]?[ \t]*\(\)/\2/v,varlambdas/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(export[ \t]+)?(public|protected|private)[ \t]+(static[ \t]+)?(abstract[ \t]+)?(((get|set)[ \t]+)|(async[ \t]+[*]*[ \t]*))?([a-zA-Z1-9_$]+)/\9/m,members/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(export[ \t]+)?interface[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\2/i,interfaces/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(export[ \t]+)?type[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\2/t,types/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*(export[ \t]+)?enum[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\2/e,enums/
--regex-typescript=/^[ \t]*import[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)/\1/I,imports/
```

and jumping to definition etc works just fine, but when i show my tags bar, nothing is there!

for reference, here is my [vimrc file](https://gist.github.com/abbood/cad3d31bb1804a05796942e5916929b9), and my [ctags file](https://gist.github.com/abbood/7b5ef4229b955ba73afe2b7047ab23d0)

[image]

## update

i added this to my .vimrc:

```
let g:tagbar_type_typescript = {                                                  
  \ 'ctagsbin' : 'tstags',                                                        
  \ 'ctagsargs' : '-f-',                                                           
  \ 'kinds': [                                                                     
    \ 'e:enums:0:1',                                                               
    \ 'f:function:0:1',                                                            
    \ 't:typealias:0:1',                                                           
    \ 'M:Module:0:1',                                                              
    \ 'I:import:0:1',                                                              
    \ 'i:interface:0:1',                                                           
    \ 'C:class:0:1',                                                               
    \ 'm:method:0:1',                                                              
    \ 'p:property:0:1',                                                            
    \ 'v:variable:0:1',                                                            
    \ 'c:const:0:1',                                                              
  \ ],                                                                            
  \ 'sort' : 0                                                                    
\ }
```

I also found out that when i run tagbar, I get this error message:

[image]

> Tagbar: could not execute ctags for /path/to/file.ts!

note: my *same* tagbar setup works perfectly fine for my php files:

[image]

Comment: Did you read `:help tagbar-extend`? There is also a section on Typescript in the [tagbar wiki](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki#typescript).

Comment: I only use tagbar for a short time, I think tagbar create tags in real time, maybe something wrong with your tag build command.

Comment: updated question to address both comments @Ralf

Comment: @dedowsdi where exactly is my tag build command? how do i debug it?

Comment: Looking at your `g:tagbar_type_typescript`, I guess you now need an executable called `tstags`.

Comment: @abbood If you are certain you have tstags executable,  you can grep the error text "Could not execute" in tagbar source code, set a breakpoint there, then you can debug whatever you want.

Comment: @Ralf that did it.. it works now! I'll put an answer to my own question, i'll give you right answer if you do though

Answer (score 1):

The bug was happening b/c I didn't have tstags executive installed..
so i got it from [here](https://github.com/Perlence/tstags) and built it like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/Perlence/tstags.git

npm install -g
$home/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/bin/tstags -> $home/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/lib/node_modules/tstags/bin/tstags.js
+ tstags@0.1.0
added 14 packages in 3.518s

$ which tstags
$home/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/bin/tstags
```

and it worked like a charm!

Comment: it is perfectly fine and I believe it is even recommended to mark your own answer as accepted, if you happen to find it before you get one from somebody else